# using array.splice() first parameter undefined, still works

Tags: javascript

I have an array that I am calling .splice() on. By accident, sometimes the code runs with `undefined` as the first parameter eg.

```
array.splice(undefined, 1);
```

but my code still works as though it was being called like:

```
array.splice(0,1);
```

So my question is, why does this work? Why does the following work?

```
[0, 1,2,3].splice(undefined,1); //returns 0
```

Thanks

Comment: Syntax for array.splice(index,howmany,item1,.....,itemX)..you have to provide the index...

Comment: It gets undefined as zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript developer are used to *clean* the value that you pass to the function in order to always have something to work with.

In this case, we can be sure that it's not an implicit coercion, because

```
Number(undefined); //NaN
Number("text"); //NaN
```

While in *splice* function they are coerced to *0*.

It's likely that they use a bitwise operator like *>>0*

```
"2">>0        //2
-8>>0         //-8
null>>0       //0
undefined>>0  //0
"text">>0     //0
```

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) treats `falsey` values the same as `0`, and `undefined` is `falsey`.

So you could also do:

```
[0, 1,2,3].splice(false,1); //returns 0
[0, 1,2,3].splice(null,1); //returns 0
```

Comment: Great +1. Just noticed that truthy values will be treated as `1`, so `[0,1,2,3].splice((1 === 1),1);`, will return `[1]`.  Might want to add this to your answer.

Comment: @DavidDomain, Not really! `2` is a truthy value and it will be treated as `2`..not `1`

Answer (score 0):

From the [*docs*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Parameters) **`arr.slice([begin[, end]])`**, *If `begin` is `undefined`, slice begins from index `0`.`*